# Error: "Cannot find symbol - method length()" when applied on JTextField

Tags: java

I want to create a `PaliodromeChecker` but there is an error on

```
int length = txtInput.length();
```

In `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`. The error is

> cannot find symbol - method length()

Did I do any wrong with code?

```
public class checker extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JButton btnCheck;
private JLabel lblInput, lblOutput;
private JTextField txtInput;

public Q4() {
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
    lblInput = new JLabel("Enter a word:");
    lblOutput = new JLabel("Welcome to check palindrome");
    btnCheck = new JButton("Check Palindrome");

    txtInput = new JTextField(15);
    p1.add(lblInput);
    p1.add(txtInput);
    p2.add(btnCheck);
    p3.add(lblOutput);
    c.add(p1);
    c.add(p2);
    c.add(p3);
    btnCheck.addActionListener(this);

}


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   int length = txtInput.length();
    String reverse = ""; 
     for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
     reverse = reverse + txtInput.charAt(i); 

    if(txtInput.equals(reverse))
     lblOutput.setText(txtInput.getText() + "is paliodrome");
     else
      lblOutput.setText(txtInput.getText() + "is not paliodrome");
    }


public static void main(String[] args){
    Q4 myGUI = new Q4();
    myGUI.setTitle("PaliodromeChecker");
    myGUI.setSize(350,150);
    myGUI.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I've never done anything graphical in java, but it seems like [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) doesn't have a method called `length`, just like the error said. You should learn how to utilize the documentation.

Comment: thanks i use int length = txtInput.getText().length(); it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do:

```
int length = txtInput.getText().length();
```

When you have problem like that, the best thing you can do is visit the docs, see [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) and you'll conclude that there is no such a method `length()` that can be applied on *object* of type `JTextField`.

But you'll notice that there exists a method called [`getText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29) that gets the text in the component, it returns a `String`, then you can have the known [`length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) method for `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `int length = txtInput.getText().length();`

When in doubt, read the [API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

Answer (score 0):

The field you reference (`txtInput`) is a `JTextField`, which has no method `length()` - it's an on-screen widdget, what do you expect?

It looks like you want to get its text...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: `txtInput.getText().length()`

Answer (score 0):

Do it as follows

```
int length = txtInput.getText().length();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot calculate length on JTextField
instead use getText on JTextField,then calculate length.

Answer (score 0):

Use `int length = txtInput.getText().length()`

`txtInput.getText()` returns a string and you can call the `length()` method to determine the length.